# language by domain in Django

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

**Is there any braindead simple way to select the language specific version of a page on a Django website based on the domain?** (the URLs are and will be the same for both languages, except the language code, so I want to have `mysite.com/teachers/manage` same as `mysite.com/en/teachers/manage` (done with 'en' default) and `mesito.es/teachers` to be same as `mesito.es/es/teachers` - and no, **the urls themselves like 'teachers/manage' will never be translated**, so I don't want to configure 2 sets of urls for both languages).

Note: *All other solutions I've found imply that I also want to translate the URLs, but I know I will never want to translate the URLs and manae 2 sets of them for this particular website.*

Note 2 (forgot to add): Most of the website is actually django-cms based, so django-cms specific solutions would be helpful to...

---

OK, I got what I wanted with this ugly hack through a redirecting view (but still, isn't there a **right** AND **simple** way to do this?...):

```
## mysite.urls:

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'mysite.views.language_router')


## mysite.views:

def language_router(request):
    if request.META['HTTP_HOST'].find('myspanishdomain.com') != -1 \
            and request.META['PATH_INFO'] == '/' :
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.myspanishdomain.com/es/')
    return cms.views.details(request, '')
```

(site at myenglishdomain.com has the default language english)

Comment: What other solutions have you looked at?

Comment: I cameover this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/271/ and digged through django sites docs but I don't want to create different site... if only the request.path would contain the goddamn language prefix in it I could hack a redirecting view or somethink ugly but workable... but not even this works as expected. i18n and l10n is indeed a bitch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Transurlvania](https://github.com/trapeze/transurlvania) as it allows you to map a domain to a language:

```
MULTILANG_LANGUAGE_DOMAINS = {
    'en': ('www.example-en.com', 'English Site'),
    'fr': ('www.example-fr.com', 'French Site')
}
```

Comment: thanks! yep, this is probably what I'll use once I refactor the codebase a bit and make it use the sites framework... but I'll keep the ugly hack above in place until I have the time/reason to do things properly.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you write your onw tiny [middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that you add after the [LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), that simply adds the language, if no language has been identified yet based on the rules that you have explained here in that thread.

Comment: Middleware written exactly for this purpose https://7webpages.com/blog/switch-language-regarding-of-domain-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate [site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) for each domain, and use a view mixin or a middleware to check the site id and react appropriately.

Comment: that's the problem, I don't want a custom site. the current site uses a mix of django-cms for some pages and some custom apps for the others and I don't want to change anything about it.

Comment: So, the second paragraph of the linked docs explain, "Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way." It's a good way to use one codebase on multiple domains.

Comment: I think Transurlvania as linked by Tini looks pretty cool too, though.

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the proper way to do it... I'll just choose Tini's answer becase Transurlvania is what I decided to use and it's specifically about this...